# Prepare data input for tensorflow from numpy and scipy.sparse

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy, tensorflow-datasets

How to prepare data for input into a tensorflow model (say a keras Sequential one) ?

I know how to prepare `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_test` and `y_test` using numpy and scipy (eventually pandas, `sklearn` style) where `train`/`test` datas are train and test datas for training a neural model, and `x`/`y` stand for a 2D sparse matrix and a 1D numpy array representing integer labels of the same size as the number of raws in the `x` data.

I'm struggling with the [Dataset documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#reading_input_data) without many insight so far ...

So far, I could only convert the scipy.sparse matrix into a [tensorflow.SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/sparse_tensor) using something like

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import sparse as sp

x = sp.csr_matrix( ... )
x = tf.SparseTensor(indices=np.vstack([*x.nonzero()]).T, 
                    values=x.data, 
                    dense_shape=x.shape)
```

and I can convert the numpy array into a [tensorflow.Tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) using something like

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

y = np.array( ... ) # 1D array of len == x.shape[0]
y = tf.constant(y)
```

- How to align the `x` and `y` into a single Dataset in order to construct the batch, buffers, ... and benefit from the Dataset utilities ?
- Should I use either `zip`, `from_tensor_slices`, or any other method of the [tensorflow.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) module ?

Examples of `x` and `y` are

```py
x = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1, 2], dense_shape=[3, 4])
y = tf.constant(np.array(range(3)))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for `x` and `y`?

Comment: @AloneTogether Added in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `tf.data.Data.from_tensor_slices`, since you mention that "y is a 1D numpy array representing integer labels of the same size as the number of rows in the x data":

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1, 2], dense_shape=[3, 4])
y = tf.constant(np.array(range(3)))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))

for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y)
```

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor([[0]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([1], shape=(1,), dtype=int32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([4], shape=(1,), dtype=int64)) tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64)
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor([[2]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([4], shape=(1,), dtype=int64)) tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([], shape=(0,), dtype=int32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([4], shape=(1,), dtype=int64)) tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. I also have to use an Input layer to tell keras to unfold the sparse data, as explained there: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/sparse_tensor#tfkeras